# Disabled property in v-for based on prop of component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Say I have this:

```
<v-btn v-for="action in actions" :key="action.icon" :disabled="action.disabled" icon
       @click="action.click(item.id)">
  <v-icon>{{ action.icon }}</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

And actions is defined like this:

```
export default {
  props: {
    rowEditingDisabled: Boolean,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      actions: [
        {icon: 'mdi-pencil', disabled: this.rowEditingDisabled, click: this.edit},
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

How can I make it so the disabled property is updated when the component prop 'rowEditingDisabled' gets updated?

This is a snippet demonstrating what I mean:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <v-btn :disabled="rowEditingDisabled">This works!</v-btn>
      <v-btn v-for="action in actions" :key="action.icon" :disabled="action.disabled" icon
         @click="action.click(item.id)">
        <v-icon>{{ action.icon }}</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </div>`,
  props: {
    rowEditingDisabled: Boolean,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      actions: [
        {icon: 'mdi-pencil', disabled: this.rowEditingDisabled, click: this.edit},
      ],
    };
  },
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      isDisabled: true
    };
  },
  created() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled;
    }, 1000);
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <child :row-editing-disabled="isDisabled"></child>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

It works when I just use the prop, but when I put it in an array it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that you watch the changes in the prop, like this:

```
export default {
    props: { rowEditingDisabled: Boolean, },
    data() {
        return {
            actions: [{
                icon: 'mdi-pencil',
                disabled: false, 
                click: this.edit
            }], 
        }; 
    },
    watch: { 
        rowEditingDisabled: function(newVal, oldVal) { 
            // watch it
            console.log('Prop changed: ', newVal, ' | was: ', oldVal);
            this.actions[0].disabled = newVal;
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually works and is what I'm doing now. At first I wanted it to accept any kind of variable, so you could pass new actions from parent components and they would be disabled based on the disabled property of the action. But it looks like the only way to do this is to work with watch. It's a bit more code this way, but as long as it works I guess it's fine.
Maybe someone else has a solution for what I was thinking of, but if not I'll accept this answer tomorrow.

Comment: the more you avoid using watch, the better would be the performance. Check out my solution

Answer (score 0):

From the `data()` method, you can reference the component's properties using `this.`

Can you try this **:**

```
data() {
    return {
      actions: [
        {icon: 'mdi-pencil', disabled: this.rowEditingDisabled, click: this.edit},
      ],
    };
  }
```

**Update :** Created a working sample code snippet as per my understanding mentioned above and it is working fine. Can you please cross check the naming convention of the `props` in template, It should be hyphen separated. i.e. `:row-editing-disabled="..."`.

Working Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('post', {
  template: '#post-template',
  props: {
    rowEditingDisabled: Boolean
  },
  data() {
    return {
      actions: [
        {icon: 'mdi-pencil', disabled: this.rowEditingDisabled, click: this.edit}
      ]
    };
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isRowEditingDisabled: true,
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <post :row-editing-disabled="isRowEditingDisabled"></post>
</div>

<template id="post-template">
  <button v-for="action in actions" :key="action.icon" :disabled="action.disabled">
    Click Me!
  </button>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Sorry, what you posted was actually the code I wanted to post. What I posted first was me trying to do something else witch watch.
Interestingly enough, while this is the most straightforward way, it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Lyxodius I updated the answer with the working code snippet. Hope it will help you in finding the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes props might be recieved with some delay. In such cases to preserve dynamicity you can make use of computed. Please check the modified lines below

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <v-btn v-for="action in actions" :key="action.icon" :disabled="disableRow" @click="action.click(item.id)"> <!-- ***Changes here*** -->
        <v-icon>{{ action.icon }}</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </div>`,
  props: {
    rowEditingDisabled: Boolean,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      actions: [
        {icon: 'mdi-pencil', click: this.edit},// ***Changes here***
      ],
    };
  },
 // ***Changes here below***
 computed: {
   disableRow() {
    return this.rowEditingDisabled;
   }
 }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      isDisabled: true
    };
  },
  created() {
    // ***Changes here***
    // Commenting the below becoz it changes the flag to false
    /* setInterval(() => {
      this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled;
    }, 1000); */
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <child :row-editing-disabled="isDisabled"></child>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Unfortunately this is not what I was looking for, because this only works if the variable is inside the child component. I was probably not precise enough in my original post. What I was looking for was a way to give any variable to it via an action array. So for example I could later add more actions from parent components that contain a variable and updating that would also update the disabled status. What you wrote works when the variable is inside the child component, which is ok for the case in my example, but not for values outside of the child component.

Comment: @Lyxodius If you observe very carefully, there is no variable that I have used inside child component. All I do is use the props via computed. 
Eventually when you pass more action attributes from parent and this implementation is scalable for future usecases as well

Comment: Hi @Amaarockz.

This solutions is much better than using the watcher, but in my case, I am not able to use either of these. I opened a question and will be happy if you can check it out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383445/disabled-property-is-not-updating-properly-in-v-select