# Disabled property is not updating properly in v-select

Tags: vue.js, select, vuejs2, vuetify.js, disabled-control

I have problem with the `disabled` property of a v-select item. I have found some solutions for such problems like using a [watcher or computed method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72173271/disabled-property-in-v-for-based-on-prop-of-component), however, I am not able to do so (or I do not know how exactly). Here is my code (**EDITED**):

```js
<template>
    <v-card class="design-card border-radius-10px" width="25%">
        <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
            ...
            <v-tab-item :value="'tab-2'">
                <v-card flat height="10vh">
                    <v-card-text>
                        <v-checkbox
                            v-model="showConditions"
                            :label="'Show conditions'"
                            hide-details
                            @change="changeShowConditions()"
                        />
                    </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
                
                <v-card>
                    <div v-for="(condition, i) in conditions" :key="i" class="conditions-container">
                        ...
                        <v-card-text class="pb-0">
                            ...
                            <v-row>
                                <v-col cols="7" class="pt-0">
                                    <v-select
                                        :ref="`goTo${i}`"
                                        v-model="condition.goTo"
                                        class="border-radius-10px"
                                        :items="allItems"
                                        :rules="checkSelfId(condition.selectedCondition._id)"
                                        :disabled="condition.disableSelection"
                                        :no-data-text="$t('noDataAvailable')"
                                        item-text="name"
                                        item-value="_id"
                                        solo
                                        @change="changeGoTo()"
                                    >
                                        <template v-slot:[`item`]="{ item }">
                                            {{ getNameInLocale(item) }}
                                        </template>

                                        <template #selection="{ item }">
                                            <div class="ml-1">
                                                <go-to-type
                                                    :value="item.type"
                                                    :show-label="false"
                                                    :show-as-button="true"
                                                    :button-label="`${getSelectedIndex(item)}.`"
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                        </template>
                                    </v-select>
                                </v-col>

                                <v-col cols="5" class="pt-0">
                                    <v-checkbox
                                        v-model="condition.disableSelection"
                                        class="text-sm-caption"
                                        label="Disable condition selection"
                                        hide-details
                                        dense
                                        @change="changeDisableCondition($event, i)"
                                    />
                                </v-col>
                            </v-row>
                        </v-card-text>
                    </div>
                </v-card>
            </v-tab-item>
        </v-tabs-items>
    </v-card>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'ComponentName',
        data() {
            return {
                ...
                showConditions: false,
                conditions: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeShowConditions() {
                if (showConditions)
                    this.generateInitialConditions()
                else
                    conditions: []
            },
            generateInitialConditions() {
                this.conditions = [
                    {
                        conditionQuestion: { ...this.selectedCondition[0] },
                        goTo: 'next'
                        disableSelection: false
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Since the conditions is an array of objects, I was not able to set a watcher. Additionally, the computed methods are not an option, too, because I do not know which condition of all I want to disable, thus, I need to pass somewhere the index. I made a method `changeDisableCondition` where I manually set the disabled property of the element by its reference `'goTo${i}'`, but it throws an error for mutating problems. I also tried to add deep watcher, but it looks like when the checkbox changes the `condition.disableSelection`, it does not take effect immediately as an event . The strange thing is that if I do `console.log(conditions[i].disableSelection)` in the `changeDisableCondition` method, it properly shows the correct boolean value. Whenever I update something on the page, it will use the new boolean value.

***UPDATE:***

Current (temporary) solution that I've found is just to initialize an empty object in the array, thus, the property becomes reactive as expected. Here is the code:

```js
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'ComponentName',
        data() {
            return {
                ...
                showConditions: false,
                conditions: []
            }
        },
        created() {
            //* Add empty object to activate the reactivity
            //* PS. This can be moved as a method, but keep it here for the example
            this.conditions = [
                {
                    conditionQuestion: {},
                    goTo: 'next',
                    disableSelection: false
                }
            ]
        },
        methods: {
            changeShowConditions() {
                if (showConditions)
                    this.generateInitialConditions()
                else
                    conditions: []
            },
            generateInitialConditions() {
                this.conditions = [
                    {
                        conditionQuestion: { ...this.selectedCondition[0] },
                        goTo: 'next'
                        disableSelection: false
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Would need to see also the actual code. Is that property set in the object from the start so it can be made reactive? If it doesn't exist when the binding happens then changing the value won't be noticed

Comment: I would suggest you to have a computed property that recieves an argument
Not sure about the syntax in vue3
```
const checkDisable = computed((index) => {
   return conditions[index].disableSelection; // where conditions is a reactive variable
}
```
or 
 ```
const checkDisable = computed(() => {
   return index => conditions[index].disableSelection; // where conditions is a reactive variable
}
```
and then
```
:disabled="checkDisable(i)"
```

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, actually, the property is not populated when the page is loaded. The conditions array is filled when another actions is taken from the user. However, is there a way to solve this? For example, making the property reactive and the change to be noticed? Btw, I updated the code above.

Comment: @Amaarockz, I do not think that this can be achieved, and I am using Vue2. The problem is that the computed properties/methods cannot receive arguments.

Comment: thats were the twist is
you can make computed recieve the arguments like
```
computed: {
  checkDisable() {
    return (index) =>  this.conditions[index].disableSelection;
 }
}
```

Comment: the above hack is not available in the official docs

Comment: Hm. Should this work in Vue2 ? It does not work when I implement it the way you said. The thing is that any method that I put, or condition, in the `:disabled`, it does not fire when I click the checkbox.

Comment: @Amaarockz, I decided to handle this by initializing an empty object in `created()` hook. It then works as expected.